# Problem with Angular website on Edge only: SCRIPT5022 expected identifier string or number

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

We just launched our website but I'm facing a problem on Edge. I can't figure out where the error is coming from, I made sure there is no rest syntax in any script.

This is our website: https://bubblydoo.be/nl

If you have other feedback regarding the website, you can definitely let me know!

Comment: Please check the polyfills.ts file, make sure you have uncomment the related import reference for the IE/Edge browser.

Comment: Code should be included in the question, not linked to your site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that some modules, including picomatch, were not transpiled to ES5, and webpack doesn't transpile any node_modules, it just takes them as is. Picomatch was included by an internal library that was bundled by Rollup, so I used babel (`rollup-plugin-babel`) to transpile it:

```
babel({
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!picomatch)/,
})
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. Webpack was splitting out one bundle for old browsers which support the `type=module` tag and another bundle for older browsers which don't support it. However, even though Edge does support the module tag, there is some code inside the `vendors.bundle.js` stemming from `node_modules` which is incompatible with the current version of Edge. When I manually switched Edge to use the "old browser" bundle, the app ran fine - so apparently the code needs transpilation for Edge still.