# Angular app works in Chrome but not in Edge with SCRIPT5022: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: angular, webpack, microsoft-edge

I have a large Angular 9 CLI application, which uses a custom webpack configuration to permit the reference to variables from JSON files into SCSS files.

It works well in Chrome but fails in Edge.

The console trace is roughly the same for the production build that I host in AWS Lamdba + ALB

and the unbundled site (ng serve)
[image]

I am puzzled that the Edge devtools locate the issue at position (1,1) in the index file:
[image]

This is my custom webpack config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

module.exports = function(defaultConfig) {
  // console.log('>>>>> debug default config rules', defaultConfig.module.rules);
  const config = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
              options: {
                implementation: require('node-sass'),
                sassOptions: {
                  // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                  precision: 8,
                  importer: jsonImporter(),
                  outputStyle: 'expanded'
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  return merge(defaultConfig, config);
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*", "app/*", "test/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.stories.ts"
  ]
}
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-public": "ng build --configuration=gopub",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "doc": "node src/scripts/runMarked.js",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^10.0.1",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@material/chips": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/vega": "^3.2.0",
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.5",
    "marked": "^0.8.0",
    "msal": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "vega": "^5.9.1",
    "vega-embed": "^6.2.2",
    "vega-lite": "^4.12.0",
    "vega-typings": "^0.12.4",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.3.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "ng-mocks": "^9.6.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "node-sass-json-importer": "^4.1.2",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

What strategy may I follow to find where the issue actually originates from ?

Comment: Do you have any `const { someProperty, ...rest } = something` ? Edge is not supporting it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with Angular website on Edge only: SCRIPT5022 expected identifier string or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502621/problem-with-angular-website-on-edge-only-script5022-expected-identifier-string)

Comment: @nevzatopcu, I did a wide search and don't have any of that.

Comment: @Roy, I chanced on that thread indeed, but I am afraid I do not understand whether it's the same issue, and even if it was, what is explained there is cryptic to me.

Comment: Can you please inform us which exact version of the MS Edge legacy browser you are using for making this test? If you are testing with the older version then make a test with the latest version to see whether it helps to fix the issue. Check whether you are importing the PolymerElement.js in your project or not. I found in another thread that it is causing a similar error in the Edge browser.

Comment: The version panel indicates: "Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0" and "Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763". I searched my code and there isn't any trace of PolymerElement.js in it or its dependencies...

Comment: I suggest you check your dependencies one by one. It may help you to find the problematic dependency and then you check whether you are using its latest version of it or not. Also, try to make tests with its previous versions may help to fix the error. You can see similar kind of issue was discussed here. https://github.com/cormacrelf/angular-skyhook/issues/430

Comment: Can you show your polyfills.ts file ?

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/error-and-status-codes#javascript-run-time-errors), error code `SCRIPT5022` related to a js exception. Maybe it will help someone. My wild guess it could be the bundle target is not compatible with Edge.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53628230/8144405 (maybe one of the libraries is using object destructuring)

Comment: Perhaps this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886539/8144405

Comment: In the debugger tab, click the button that looks like a stop sign and set it the setting to break on all exceptions.

Comment: @David, good idea: I tried breaking on all exceptions, but I got the error without hitting any exception

Comment: @BuZz And it's not possible at all that you make your compiled files available for us somehow?

Comment: Its also worth checking any 3rd party packages you are using, and their compatibility.  It could be one of them does not have IE support.

Comment: @David, it's a little tough. It's full of hints of who the code owners are and what it is, but I've started doing a trimmed down version for sharing

Comment: @SrishtiKhandelwal, my polyfills.ts only includes `import 'web-animations-js'; import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof, added package.json

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the below code in index.html in head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip - unfortunately this doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

Such this errors may occur when you **misplace comma in case of creating dynamic object**. For example you may create an object like below:

```
var dynamicObject = {
   id: 23,
   isProperty: false,
   name: 'sth',  // <-- redundant comma
}
```

Creating objects on the fly won't be strongly typed also. The best way is taking advantage of `interface` or `class`. You may have such this definition in a part of the entire project, not only the page you get the error.

**Another reason** could be *using a **reserved** keyword in Internet Explorer or Edge* as a `key` inside a `dictionary`, So you have to rename it or enclose the key in quotes. For example `class` is one the reserved ones. **Note that** both IE and Edge use the same JavaScript engine named [Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JavaScript_engine)).

Comment: I've come across a few blogs detailing those possible issues. I checked already and don't have the "comma" issue, nor am I using any reserved words inappropriately